# ISAPI Rewrite 3 - Folder? (Windows IIS 7 Server)

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, isapi

So I have ISAPI Rewrite 3 (Helicon) installed on my Server Windows IIS 7 Server and the service is running.

In the Rewrite Manager, I have added a very simple rule (for all IIS Websites) that will redirect all requests to test.html. This is how it looks like:

```
# Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite configuration file
# Version 3.1.0.87

RewriteEngine on 

RewriteRule .* test.html
```

This, however, does not work at all. What did I miss? I'm pretty much a novice. Is that a folder problem? Do I have to specify a RewriteBase? If so, what's the value - / does not work. Thansk!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems that could be preventing the software from working properly, but off the top of my head here are some that I've run into...

1. In the free version of Helicon APE you have to enable htaccess processing for a given IIS website instance.  You can access this via the Help menu, not sure if or where this exists in IR3.
2. Try the troubleshooting steps from the documentation:
   http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/doc/troubleshooting.htm

   This link shows you how to enable debug logging for the rewrite module so you can get more specific info about your problem.

I too had issues with IR3 the last time I used it (long ago, and I don't remember the specifics.) I've since switched to APE - http://www.helicontech.com/download-ape.htm and have been very pleased with the product.